# Why is last day of this year week 1 in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

Why is this showing week 1? Although it's last day of year 2012.
to_char( to_date('31-DEC-12'), 'IW' )

Comment: Dec 30-Jan 5 is the new week. Sun-Sat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, according to the ISO standard, we are in week 1.

http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php?year=2013

The date format `IW` in Oracle returns the

> Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

For a non-ISO based year, you can try using the format `WW`.

Comment: My problem here is trunc(sysdate) shows year 2012. Effecting my reports.

Comment: Well then your reports have not been coded correctly. What date are you expecting to actually have returned? If week 53, check my update about using the format `WW`.